# Why is Chrome displaying a "brighter" red when applying a brightness(1.5) css filter to a rgb(255, 0, 0) div?

Tags: css, google-chrome, web, firefox

I am playing around with implementing some [CSS filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) and got to reading about `brightness`. [Per the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#brightnessEquivalent), `brightness` just scales each rgba channel by the given `slope`. [Earlier in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#FilterPrimitivesOverview) it mentions

> The RGBA result from each filter primitive will be clamped into the allowable ranges for colors and opacity values

This should mean that, if I have the following div

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color: rgb(255,0,0);">My guess</div>
```

so just a red square, and compare it to this div

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color: rgb(255,0,0); filter:brightness(1.5)">Actual</div>
```

then I should get the same color. Since 255 * 1.5 > 255, the red value should be clamped down to 255, thus remaining the same. However, on Chrome there is a very noticeable difference.

```html
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color: rgb(255,0,0);">My guess</div>
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color: rgb(255,0,0); filter:brightness(1.5)">Actual</div>
```

in chrome

[image: chrome]

Firefox displays them as the same color.

[image: Firefox displays]

Anyone know what is going on in Chrome to make this happen? I am expecting them to be the same and just wrote the mentioned html to compare.

Comment: It’s possible you have the wrong part of the spec. In the MDN link you have look at the values for brightness. Values over 1 are allowed and will alter the brightness. I tried 1.5 and 1.75 and they give different results testing in Safari iOS.

Comment: @AHaworth are you talking about the value that goes into the brightness function? If so then yeah you can have a value over 1, and that could potentially change the color. Based on what I was reading it should depend if the product of that value and the channel value go over 255. You could have something like rgb(50,25,25) then birghtness(1.5) and brightness(1.75) would be different.

Answer (score 1):

That will depend on the color profile of your monitor. Certainly you have a wide gamut profile (P3 or alike), which does allow for values higher than 1.0.

It is not yet per specs, and it seems Chrome is just dragging things up here, but you should probably not expect the color channels to be limited to sRGB's `1.0`/`255` anymore. The [`color()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color) function allows us to set higher ranges already:

```html
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color: rgb(255,0,0);">My guess</div>
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color: rgb(255,0,0); filter:brightness(1.5)">Actual</div>
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color: color(srgb 1.5 0 0);">color(srgb 1.5 0 0) </div>
```

You might be interested in [this discussion](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/7100) where this discrepancy is evoked and where Simon Fraser (representing WebKit) [says](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/7100#issuecomment-1103076672)

> WebKit does compositing in the colorspace of the display.

and Christopher Cameron (representing Chromium) [says](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/7100#issuecomment-1104166869)

> Chrome does compositing in the colorspace of the display. We also do rasterization in the colorspace of the display.
>
> There are some exceptions. If the display has a color space that is too far from sRGB-like interoplationbehavior (e.g, has a linear or PQ transfer function), then we do composite and raster in extended-sRGB, and do a final blit converting to linear or PQ.
>
> We haven't carefully quantified exactly what "too far from sRGB-like interpolation behavior" means (you can examine the current logic here).